# How to display div by jquery if user dont perform any activity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

facing a problem with html page with jquery
want to show a div if user not perform any activity for 20 secs.
i am able to show and hide it using jquery by unable to set time for it
code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#VisitWidget").hide();
        $("#VisitWidget").show();`
        $('#BtnBook').click(function () {
            $("#VisitWidget").slideToggle();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        if ($(document).data('events')) {
            $("#VisitWidget").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#VisitWidget").hide();
        }
    }, 2000);
}); 
< /script>
```

//

```
$(document).data('events') will check if there are any events on the page..
```

Comment: Do you mean `$(document).data('events')` ?

Comment: @Miszy .. Yes I meant that.. Thanks for pointing it out .. Corrected the typo

Comment: @sushant reddy thnks i got solution above one is working and your also

Answer (score 0):

This waits for mouse move activity and if 20 seconds go by, it'll show your div.

```
var mouseTimeout;

$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    clearTimout(mouseTimeout);

    mouseTimeout = setTimeout(
        function(){
        $("#VisitWidget").slideToggle(); 
    },
    20000); // 20 seconds
});
```

Comment: I'd go with jQuery/listener rather then setting `document.onmousemove` http://jsfiddle.net/m2bxZ/

Comment: Touche, I'll add that in there